# Calculate the length of text

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to calculate the length of a text written by TikZ?

I would like to fit a word inside circle. But sometimes the word is to long for the circle. So my idea was to calculate the length of the text and to adjust the font size if the text is too long.

Comment: `width("some text here")`. Sort of related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373941/flow-chart-with-defined-width-for-the-boxes/374271#374271

Comment: Also see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284314/specify-width-height-of-rectangle-around-text-using-tikz and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225533/balanced-text-wrapping-in-parbox.

Answer (score 4):

May be a round `fitbox` (from `tcolorbox`) can help you. You just define box size and `tcolorbox` fits the text inside it. Only texts larger than provided space are reduced.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newtcboxfit{\myfitbox}{%
    width = 3cm,
    square,
    circular arc,
    halign = center,
    valign = center,
    nobeforeafter
}


\begin{document}
\myfitbox{This is a long text inside a circular tcolorbox}
%
\myfitbox{This is an ever longer text inside a circular tcolorbox}
%
\myfitbox{This is a much more longer, longer and  longer text inside a circular tcolorbox}
%
\myfitbox{This is a much more longer, longer and  longer text inside a circular tcolorbox. This is a much more longer, longer and  longer text inside a circular tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]